# How to display image in FreeTextBox & Label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, textbox, freetextbox

Is it possible to display an image in a FreeTextBox? If yes, how can I do this?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I want to load images from the attachment of an EmailMessage and display it in a FreeTextBox & Label.

EDIT 2:

This is the code I use:

```
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
            new ItemView(100));
        foreach (EmailMessage item in findResults.Items)
        {
            item.Load();
            if (!list.Contains(item.Id.UniqueId))
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["OutlookID"] = item.Id.UniqueId;
                dr["Onderwerp"] = item.Subject;
                dr["Omschrijving"] = item.Body + item.Attachments;
                dr["Meldingsdatum"] = item.DateTimeSent;
                dr["Melder"] = ad.GetLoginName(item.Sender.Name);
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(item.MimeContent.Content);

                FreeTextBox1.Text += s;

            }
```

Comment: I'm using the same control at the moment and I'm displaying the images.  What is your code?

Comment: I'm using it to display the body of EmailMessages and sometimes the body contains also images. But I can't see images in freetextbox

Comment: Are the images embedded in the email or are they stored on a server?

Comment: Sorry, we don't delete questions, *two hours after they are asked*, because you haven't gotten any "good answers."  I'd suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) for hints on how to ask better questions.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5219937/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same as displaying a image using html -

```
<img src="...."/>
```

can u post a sample that u have tried

Comment: is it possible to display it by providing the byte[]-value?

Comment: yes, in firefox 4 rc freetextbox supports copy paste of images, he actually stores byte[] in this case

Comment: what i meant was that byte[] will also work and the control itself does that in some scenarios

Comment: but how can i assign byte... to freetextbox?

Comment: sorry, u have to pass base64 encoded string for ex-
<img
src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAAPAKIAAAsLav///88PD9WqsYmApmZmZtZfYmdakyH5BAQUAP8ALAAAAABQAA8AAAPb
WLrc/jDKSVe4OOvNu/9gqARDSRBHegyGMahqO4R0bQcjIQ8E4BMCQc930JluyGRmdAAcdiigMLVr
ApTYWy5FKM1IQe+Mp+L4rphz+qIOBAUYeCY4p2tGrJZeH9y79mZsawFoaIRxF3JyiYxuHiMGb5KT
kpFvZj4ZbYeCiXaOiKBwnxh4fnt9e3ktgZyHhrChinONs3cFAShFF2JhvCZlG5uchYNun5eedRxM
AF15XEFRXgZWWdciuM8GCmdSQ84lLQfY5R14wDB5Lyon4ubwS7jx9NcV9/j5+g4JADs=
" alt="British Blog Directory" width="80" height="15" />

Comment: http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do something like :

```
string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mime.Content);
FreeTextBox1.Text = s;
```

Comment: I get this error: You must load or assign this property before you can read its value.

Comment: You are assigning `mime` to the `item.MineContent`?  You could just use `item.MimeContent` in the `GetString` method.

Comment: Without knowing what is on the page, it's going to be very difficult to help.  Step through the code to find out where it is error-ing.

Comment: I work with Exchange WebService Managed API to load EmailMessages from the server

Comment: Ok, it means that you have a `null` value somewhere and it isn't working.  Unless you step through your code, you aren't going to pin point the problem.